# User opens one screen in two browser tabs and press update button within milliseconds

Tags: postgresql, transactions, database-deadlocks

I am running into one issue. Any help would be appreciated.

I am using PostgreSQL as back end.

The issue is: User opens one screen in two tabs and press update button within a second.

Example - table fields - id - is_posted

I have a flag on the table which I am setting it to true - is_posted = true and after setting this flag to true I have a trigger which inserts few records in other tables. If is_posted = true then I am not allowing the user to update that record again.

If a user clicks 'Update' button in one tab and after 1 - 2 seconds clicks 'Update' button on other tab then I get updated value and easily throw validation message that "Record already updated".

But if a user follows the same process but within milliseconds, then I do not get the updated data and record get updated twice. And it is creating multiple records in other tables which is leading to create bad data.

Kindly suggest.

Thanks,

Comment: That's a problem of your application. How does the application check if the record was already updated?

Comment: Did you try updating it like `UPDATE t SET is_posted = TRUE WHERE id = ? AND NOT is_posted`? -- BTW it has nothing to do with deadlocks.

Comment: Consider [Optimistic concurrency control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) An example of simple implementation using `version` column you can find [here](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-read-modify-write-cycles/)